# Track Windows Phone system tray state changes: battery+time or full

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, system-tray

When the Windows Phone's system tray is visible, it could be in two states partially: battery + time or full (if all data are shown). I would like to know in my application that the state is changed. Has anybody an idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the current version of the Windows Phone SDK, you can't really do this...